# XCode Debug Stops and Prints a Number

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have been debugging an iOS app written in Obj C and Swift fine for some time with Xcode 9. Now whenever I start it always stops in main.m and prints a number in the debug console.

I initially switched to wireless debugging and thought that might be related. I have since switched back to USB and the result is the same.

If I just run the app now installed on the device it launches just fine.

How can I find the cause of the problem?

[image]

Comment: Clicking continue results in another number being printed. No clue as to cause still.

Comment: What if you turn off breakpoints?

Comment: I think your application is throwing an exception... may be try turning off exceptions... and also make sure the application is not crashing.

Comment: I have no doubt there is some exception happening. What I'd like to know is what is that exception?
If I keep hitting continue it does eventually continue.

Comment: So remove your exception breakpoint and move on. It is purely internal to Cocoa and is being caught in good order. No crash. No harm.